# SELECT DAY('2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234567 -07:00') does not work?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This sql statement:

```
SELECT DAY('2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234567 -07:00');
```

is copied from the SQL Server 2012 documentation and tested in my SQL Server 2012 express edition environment. But there was an error saying

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I understand that the character type argument passed in `DAY()` is unable to be converted to a datetime type value, meaning it has the wrong format (incompatible with some current settings related to `SET DATEFORMAT` or any settings I don't know). So that's what I would like to know about. Could you explain why that sample statement (not of mine) does not work in my environment. My SQL Server instance was installed with default settings, I've not changed anything after installing it.

By modifying the input string a little, it works:

```
SELECT DAY('2007-04-30T01:01:01.123'); -- Works!
```

But these don't (saying the same error I posted at first):

```
SELECT DAY('2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234'); -- just add 4
SELECT DAY('2007-04-30T01:01:01.123 -07:00'); -- just add -07:00
```

Looks like there is some settings related to this problem, please tell me what it might be and how to fix this issue (I don't want to change the input string as I tried to make it work).

Thanks for your time solving my problem!

**UPDATE**:

Also done as some suggestions, like this:

```
SELECT DAY('2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234567-07:00');
SELECT DAY('2007-04-30T01:01:01.123-07:00');
```

but it still does not work.

Comment: You realise its only the space between `ms` and `tz` which is causing the error? This works `SELECT DAY('2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234567-07:00');`. Possibly an error in the documentation?!?

Comment: This is indeed an error in the documentation. Specifically, the documentation for [DAY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms176052) contains this erroneous example. The documentation for [datetimeoffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb630289) explicitly says "Spaces are not allowed between the datetimeoffset and the datetime parts." I've added a comment on the page to that effect.

Comment: @Jamiec Maybe that's an error but it's not exactly the problem. I've tried as what you suggested and it still says the error. (also note about the example `'2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234'` which also gives that error).

Comment: What does `SELECT DAY(CAST('2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234567-07:00' AS DATETIMEOFFSET));` produce?

Comment: @JeroenMostert casting like that of course works expectedly, I doubt that the input string is understood as `datetime` string, not `datetime2` string, but as you see the statement works in other environments not in my enviroment.

Comment: `SELECT DAY('2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234567-07:00');` should likewise work perfectly in all environments. I asked because I wanted to be sure `DATETIMEOFFSET` was, in fact, available in your environment. Stranger errors than accidentally misreporting the version of SQL Server you're using have been committed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you can be sure that my environment is SQL Server 2012 Express Edition, your code works expectedly, it supports datetime2 and datetimeoffset, ...

Comment: @JeroenMostert I would like to notify you about the solution I've just found, it's related to the compatibility level of the current database.

Comment: Believe it or not, database compatibility level was my actual guess, but I tried it and `DATETIMEOFFSET` worked even with that. I actually didn't check to see if converting the literal worked. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem. In fact the statement itself (as some ones suggested) should work, but that's just one side of the problem. The other side is the ***compatibility level*** of the current datatbase. In my case it's just `90` (which is SQL Server 2005), so explicit casting is required. By changing the compatibility level to `110` (SQL Server 2012) or explicitly casting, it works expectedly.